# Difference between newer implementation and older implementations

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I am a newbie to Fortran. Please look at the code below:

```
c   main program
    call foo(2)
    print*, 2
    stop
    end
    subroutine foo(x)
        x = x + 1
        return
    end
```

- In some implementations of Fortran IV, the above code would print a 3. Why is that? Can you suggest an explanation?
- How do you suppose more recent Fortran implementations get around the problem?

Help is very much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program breaks the language rules - the dummy argument `x` in the subroutine is modified via the line `x = x + 1`, but it is associated with something that is an expression (a simple constant).  In general, values that result from expressions cannot be modified.

That specific code is still syntactically valid Fortran 2008.  It remains a programming error in Fortran 2008 - as it was in Fortran IV/66.  This isn't something that compilers are required to diagnose.  Some *may*, perhaps with additional debugging options, and perhaps not till runtime.

Because the program breaks the language rules anything could happen when you run the program.  Exactly what depends on the code generated by the compiler.  Compilers may have set aside modifiable storage for the value that results from the expression such that it internally looks like a variable (the program might print three and the program carries on), that modifiable storage might be shared across the program for other instances of the constant `2` (suddenly the value of `2` becomes three everywhere!), the storage for the value of the constant might in non-modifiable memory (the program may crash), the compiler may issue an error message, the program may get upset and sulk in its bedroom, the program might declare war on a neighbouring nation - it is a programming error - what happens is unspecified.

As of Fortran 90, facilities were introduced into the language to allow programmers to write *new* code that is practical for compilers to check for errors such as these (and in some cases compilers are required to check for errors if they are to be regarded as standard conforming).

For the code as presented, the main program and the subroutine are to be regarded as separately compiled - the main program is unaware of the details of the subroutine and vice versa (it is possible that the subroutine could be compiled long after the main program, on a different machine, with the outputs of the two being linked together at some later stage - without fancy link time behaviour or static analysis it is therefore not possible to resolve errors such as this).  Language rules are such that when compiling the main program the compiler must implicitly assume the details of the interface of the subroutine based only on the way the subroutine is referenced - inside the main program the subroutine has an **implicit interface**.

Fortran 90 introduced the concept of an **explicit interface**, where the compiler is explicitly told what the interface of the subroutine in various ways, and can then check that any reference to the subroutine is consistent with that interface.  If a procedure is a module procedure, internal procedure or intrinsic procedure - that interface is automatically realized, alternatively for external subprograms, procedure pointers, etc, the programmer can explicitly describe the interface using an interface block.

In addition, Fortran 90 introduced the **intent attribute** - a characteristic of a dummy argument of a procedure that is also then a characteristic of the interface for a procedure.  The intent of the argument indicates to the compiler whether the procedure may define the argument (it also may implications for default initialization and component allocation status) and hence whether an expression could be a valid actual argument.  `x` in subroutine `foo` would typically be declared INTENT(INOUT).

Collectively these new language features provide a robust defence against this sort of programming error when using compilers with a basic level of implementation quality.  If you are starting with the language then it is recommended that these new features become part of your standard approach  - i.e. use implicit none, all procedures should generally be module procedures or internal procedures, use external procedures only when absolutely required, always specify dummy argument intent, use free form source.